# How can I give style to django-allauth login/signup default forms?

Tags: django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to add custom style to my login form in django-allauth. However, I don't know the name of the fields to use.

I want to do something similar to the following code, but with correct field names.

```
{{ form.email.errors }}
<div class="email">{{ form.email|html_placeholder:"Email" }}</div>
{{ form.password.errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">{{form.password|html_placeholder:"password" }}</div>
```

`html_placeholder` is nothing but a filter used to add a placeholder attribute to the field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was writing this post I found the answer myself.

If you use a default login form (that was my case), you need to find the form that is being used by default. [LoginForm](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L51) is in allauth/acoount/forms.py. There the fields `password` and `remember` are explicitly defined, and the field `login` is added within the `__init__` method.

So, in my case it would result:

```
{{ form.login.errors }}
<div class="login">{{ form.login|html_placeholder:"Email" }}</div>
{{ form.password.errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">{{form.password|html_placeholder:"password" }}</div>
```

Comment: I get : Invalid filter: 'html_placeholder' . How to fix this?